# What game is featured in the Razer Ornata Chroma Ad

Tags: game-identification

What game is on the monitor of this advertisement?

[image: Razer Ornata Chroma Ad]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's [Battlerite](https://store.steampowered.com/app/504370/Battlerite/). One of the [featured screenshots](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/504370/ss_01c1f7b8a9928b79647861e5af96f493a3db9897.jpg) includes the map shown in that ad.